# How to fix CodenameOne build upload error

Tags: codenameone

I have been running into some issues when trying to submit a build to the server. Every time I try to submit it, it fails. Here's the output of the process :

```
ant -f /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES build-for-android-device
No GUI Entries available
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build
refresh-libs:
Deleting directory /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/lib/impl
clean:
copy-android-override:
Created dir: /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/classes
copy-libs:
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/built-jar.properties
Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
        code size and wider device support
Created dir: /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/tmp
Compiling 13 source files to /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/tmp
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Created dir: /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/empty
Created dir: /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
Compiling 13 source files to /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/classes
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 1 file to /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/classes
Copied 2 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build/classes
compile:
Created dir: /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/dist
Copying 1 file to /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build
Not copying library /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/override , it's a directory.
Not copying library /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/lib/impl/cls , it's a directory.
Not copying library /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/lib/impl/stubs , it's a directory.
Not copying library /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/native/internal_tmp , it's a directory.
Copy libraries to /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/dist/lib.
Building jar: /home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/dist/DashboardFAES.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "/home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/dist/DashboardFAES.jar"
jar:
clean-override:
build-for-android-device:
You sent an android build without submitting a keystore. Notice that you will receive a build that is inappropriate for distribution (although it could be used for debugging purposes). For further details read http://www.codenameone.com/signing.html
Sending build request to the server, notice that the build might take a while to complete!
Sending build to account: mysuperaddress@gmail.com
Response message from server is: OK
Server provided no further details
java.io.IOException: An upload error occured - check that you have enough build credits on the server
    at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendS3Build(BuildProcess.java:410)
    at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendRequestToServer(BuildProcess.java:432)
    at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
/home/darklord/NetBeansProjects/DashboardFAES/build.xml:300: Error in server build process
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 minute 55 seconds)
```

Please help me out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 9 times out of 10 it means you ran out of build credits for this month which are reset every month. Notice that you can see those in the subscription tab.

In 9 times out of the remainder this is due to a bad connection/proxy configuration. You need to configure the Java proxy as well as the main process.

In the last 1 percent of the cases something might have went wrong in which case I suggest contacting us via one of our support channels.

Comment: I had just started reusing my account after a while - I have all the credits for this month. It seems there was some issues with the account, seems like my plan was not working properly. (I am just speculating here - I still haven't completely figured out what was wrong).